# Crear Histograma JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un código de Javascript que muestre un histograma de cuantas veces aparece cierto numero. El código es el siguiente:

```
const CantNum = [];
for(const numero of myArray){
    if(CantNum[numero] ===undefined)
        CantNum[numero]=0;
    CantNum[numero]++;
}

console.log(CantNum);
```

La salida que me aparece es la siguiente:

```
{ '1': 5, '2': 2, '3': 2, '5': 1 }
```

Pero se supone que la salida tendría que ser la siguiente:

```
1:*****
2:**
3:**
4:
5:*
```

Comment: para hacer los "*" n veces se hace `"*".repeat(n)`, igual no estás considerando los numeros que no están.

Comment: @Emeeus En el array son numeros del 1 al 5, el 4 no aparece. y lo de "*".repeat(n), ¿En que parte iría?

Answer (score 2):

En la salida que deberías tener se indican valores que teoricamente no aparecen, son huecos. En dicho caso se puede definir un objeto vacío con todos los valores intermedios y luego se llena. Si ese es el caso:

```js
const myArray = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,5,8];

const CantNum = {}

for (let i = 1; i <= Math.max(...myArray) ; i++){ // <-- de 1 a 8 con los intermedios

          CantNum[i] = ""; 

}

myArray.forEach(e=>CantNum[e] += "*"); // <-- Agregamos un * por cada aparición

console.log(CantNum);
```

Comment: Sugerencia: probablemente un `repeat` quedaría mejor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 1):

Hola @user222374 el desarrollo de ese algoritmo seria el siguiente:

```
myArray = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1]

//Ordenar myArray
myArray.sort(); 
//console.log(myArray)

//Obtener el valor maximo del myArray
var maxArray = Math.max(...myArray)
//console.log(maxArray)

// Recorrer los # 1 al valox max e imprimirlos
a = ''
for(i=1; i <= maxArray; i++) {
    //Imprimimos el # a contar
    a = (i + ": ");

    //Recorrer array para imprimir * por cada vez que encontremos el numero actual i
    b = ''
    for(x=0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    //si # actual i es = # en la pocision x del array imprime *
        if (i == myArray[x]) {
            b = (b + "*")
        }
    }
    console.log(a +  b)
    // Salto linea al final de imprimir los * o vacio en caso de no encontrar el #
    //console.log();
}
```